# Is it possible to retrieve data inside an XAML file?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In an application I need to use some custom object where each have their own properties and these properties coming from a database so in

```
 <Style x:Key="key1" TargetType="Rectangle">

        <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill"/>
        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="s:Prop.ID" Value="1234567890-ABC" />
    </Style>
```

I must assign values to the properties. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

You can use TryFindResource(object key).  For example, if your style is under your window's resources and you want to set the second setter to true, you can put this in the code-behind:

```
((TryFindResource("key1") as Style).Setters[1] as Setter).Value = true;
```

You could also use [binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx?ppud=4).  Just set the value to `Value="{Binding Path=path}"` and make your path a dependency property.  This also works with [multibinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) and conversion.

Comment: note that `TryFindResource` returns `null` if the object is not found, thus there is a potential `NullReferenceException` here.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that.  Though I'm using it right now in what I'm working on, and I've never had that problem.

Comment: I'm assuming TryFindResource() has nothing to do with database so binding might be solution to my case. right?

Comment: Probably.  Sorry, I don't know much about databases yet.

Comment: no I appreciate your response now I have learned something about it which I had no idea  before. I am going to look at Mares' link seems close to what I'm looking for. Thanks to you all

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps MVVM will help you out. Then you have a ViewModel, which exposes your properties to the view. The Model is what the database will deliver. The ViewModel is an adapter between model and view.

Jason Dollinger explains it very good in his video which is [available here](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650)

Comment: Hello Mare, I'm in the middle of a wpf project and not familiar with MVVM so is that something that I can do in my project or I had to design it base on MVVM in the first place?

Comment: i believe you can start using MVVM at any point. especially to solve that kind of problem. but you will end up using MVVM anywhere then, as it is plain, simple and a good solution for most of these settings.